# Is there any way to force a Xeon 1650 v3 CPU to not change its operating frequency?

Tags: cpu, xeon, supermicro, cpu-throttling

I have a SuperMicro X10SRi-F server with a Xeon 1650v3 CPU. I'm trying to disable frequency scaling on the processor without any luck (don't know if it is even possible at all).

I've disabled Speed Step on the BIOS, put the machine in the 'High performance' power profile, but still see wide swings in frequency:

[image: Too low frequency on many cores]

I really need all the power the machine can give me (I'm recording and playing broadcast video).

Is there any way to fix the CPU frequency? Is this normal!?

Comment: Interesting. I would expect that you would want these speed swings to get more performance. As in: Lower freq and less heat production when waiting for non-CPU tasks, and more turno headroom (for a while) when you do have CPU tasks.

Comment: In the normal case, I agree, but I'm using a Matrox card for professional video, which doesn't like the frequency swings...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From SuperMicro's [How do I enable Turbo mode to get the maximum Turbo mode speed on my X10DRi motherboard?](http://www.supermicro.com/support/faqs/faq.cfm?faq=21555):

> Please make sure the following settings are correct:
>
> 1. Please make sure all cores are enabled: Advanced >> CPU Configuration >> Core enabled >> “0” to enable all cores.
> 2. Under the Bios setup go to: Advanced >> CPU Configuration >> Advanced Power Management and make sure the setting are as follows: 
>      Power Technology >> Custom
>
> Energy performance Tuning >> disable
>
> Energy performance BIAS setting >> performance
>
> Energy efficient turbo >> disable
>
> 3. Then go to Advanced >> CPU Configuration >> Advanced Power Management >> CPU P state control and make sure the settings are as
>      follows  EIST (P-States) >> Enable
>
> Turbo mode >> enable
>
> P-state coordination >> HW_ALL
>
> 4. Then Advanced >> CPU Configuration >> Advanced Power Management >> CPU C state control and make sure the setting are as follows.
>      Package C-state limit >> C0/C1 state
>
> CPU C3 Report >>disable
>
> CPU C6 report >> enable
>
> Enhanced Halt state >> disable

Note: The FAQ is referring to a different MB model, but it's very similar, and the BIOS options are the same according to [the X10SRi manual](ftp://ftp.supermicro.com/CDR-X10-UP_1.13_for_Intel_X10_UP_platform/MANUALS/X10SRi-F.pdf).

Comment: I'll verify this once I get access to the server again and then mark the answer as correct. Thank you!

Comment: I marked this as an answer as the frequency changes a lot less, but it still changes...any other ideas to try?

Answer (score 2):

Just stumbled on a program called Throttlestop (freeware), that does a lot for you without messing around in the BIOS. It monitors also the heat of the processor, and you can change the settings without restart (like when you change the BIOS-settings).

You find it at https://www.techpowerup.com/download/techpowerup-throttlestop/.

Check if your processortype is supported (Core 2 and Core i). You read more at
http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/the-throttlestop-guide.531329/.

Right now this program has 'pumped up' my far too slow HP Pavilion g7 (out of warranty anyway) with a core I7-3612QM, max frequency 2.1 Ghz, that I could not get run higher than about 0,67 Ghz. Now I have doubled that to around 1,3 Ghz, while the temperature raised only from 72°C to 87°C.

Now I have the performance I need for some processor hungry tasks, so I stop trying to go faster.

Rudolf van Roosmalen

Comment: Nope, nope, nope! Your CPU throttles itself for reasons, and forcing it to go faster is asking for trouble. You should investigate WHY your CPU doesn't want to run higher than 670Mhz because there is probably a reason. Also, running at 87C for prolonged periods of time is NOT a good idea, especially on a mobile device which typically has less cooling capability.

Answer (score 1):

I have same troubles with Super Micro X10DAi motherboard, but solution was completely different even that board is from X10 family also.

I have to

1. Advanced >> CPU Configuration >> Clock Spread Spectrum >> **Enabled**
2. Advanced >> CPU Configuration >> Advanced Power Management Configuration >> Power Technology >> **Disabled**

I have on this motherboard two processors Xeon E5-2620 v3

[Clocks Stable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1A96.jpg)